# Installing python package on AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I have deployed my `zipped` project without `psycopg2` package. I want to install this package on my `lambda` without re-uploading my fixed project (i haven't access to my project right now). How can i install this `package` on my `lambda`? Is it possible to do it with `pip`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do with `pip`. You have to add the dependency to your zipped Lambda deployment file. You can't modify your Lambda deployment without uploading a new zipped deployment file.

Comment: and youll be reuploading your code many other times. so write yourself a deploy script

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use **pip directly on the lambda**. Rather I use a custom build script to create zip package [this can give you a brief idea - it can certainly be made much simpler]

```
rm -rf ~/devops/tempenv > /dev/null
virtualenv ~/devops/tempenv
source ~/devops/tempenv/bin/activate
pip install SlackClient
pip install PyYaml
deactivate
rm -rf temp > /dev/null
mkdir temp
rm aws-lambda.zip > /dev/null
cp -r ~/devops/tempenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/* temp/
cp *.py temp
cd temp
zip -r aws-lambda.zip .
mv aws-lambda.zip ../
cd ..
rm -rf temp
rm -rf ~/devops/tempenv
```